# jQuery - pre-set array values for add-to-cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic add-to-cart that allows for adding and removing cart items using checkboxes.

I want to be able to pre-set some of the items to be in the cart by getting the item's `id` or `data-wish` attribute and adding it to the array for the items.

```
var wish = {
  items: ["handbag", "backpack"]
};
```

How do I allow for items to be pre-selected so that they appear in the cart and the `.my-wish-add` button is `:checked` (for the icon's checked state animation).

```js
// Wish Function
var wish = {
  items: []
};
var update_product = function(product) {};

$(function() {
  //Add to wish
  var addToWish = function(product, qty) {
    qty = qty || 1;
    var wish = getWish();
    var indexOfId = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == product.id);
    if (indexOfId === -1) {
      wish.items.push({
        id: product.id,
        img: product.img,
        name: product.name,
        location: product.location,
        price: product.price
      });
      $parent = $("#" + product.id).closest(".items__cart");
      $parent
        .find(".wish-icon")
        .addClass("active")
        .attr("data-prefix", "fas");
    } else {
      wish.items[indexOfId].stock = Number(product.stock);
    }
    //Update popup wish
    updateWish(wish);
  };
  //Remove from wish on id
  var removeFromWish = function(id) {
    var wish = getWish();
    var wishIndex = wish.items.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
    wish.items.splice(wishIndex, 1);
    $parent = $("#" + id).closest(".items__cart");
    $parent
      .find(".wish-icon")
      .first()
      .removeClass("active")
      .attr("data-prefix", "far");
    //Update popup wish
    updateWish(wish);
  };

  var getProductValues = function(element) {
    var productId = $(element)
      .closest(".items__cart")
      .find(".item__tile")
      .attr("id");
    var productImg = $(element)
      .closest(".items__cart")
      .find(".item__img")
      .attr("src");
    var productName = $(element)
      .closest(".items__cart")
      .find(".item__title")
      .html();
    var productPrice = $(element)
      .closest(".items__cart")
      .find(".cost")
      .html();
    var productLocation = $(element)
      .closest(".items__cart")
      .find(".item__location")
      .html();
    var productTax = $(element)
      .closest(".items__cart")
      .find(".circle")
      .html();
    return {
      id: productId,
      img: productImg,
      name: productName,
      location: productLocation,
      price: productPrice,
      tax: productTax
    };
  };

  $(".my-wish-add").on("change", function() {
    var product = getProductValues(this);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      addToWish({
        id: product.id,
        img: product.img,
        name: product.name,
        location: product.location,
        price: product.price,
        tax: product.tax
      });
    } else {
      removeFromWish(product.id);
    }
  });
  //Update wish html to reflect changes
  var updateWish = function(wish) {
    $(".wishlist__items").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < wish.items.length; i++) {
      $(".wishlist__items").append(
        "<li class='wish__item'>" +
        '<div class="wish__thumb">' +
        "<img src='" +
        wish.items[i].img +
        "' />" +
        "</div>" +
        '<div class="wish__info">' +
        '<div class="wish__header">' +
        '<div class="wish-name">' +
        wish.items[i].name +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        ' <div class="wish__value">' +
        "<span>Price: </span> $ " +
        wish.items[i].price +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        '<div class="wish__remove">' +
        '<label class="wish__label">' +
        '<input type="checkbox" id="my-wish-remove' +
        i +
        '" class="my-wish-remove" aria-hidden="true">' +
        "<i class='fas fa-heart'></i>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>"
      );
      (function() {
        var currentIndex = i;
        $("#my-wish-remove" + currentIndex).on("change", function() {
          $(this)
            .closest("li")
            .hide(400);
          setTimeout(function() {
            wish.items[currentIndex].stock = "";
            update_product(wish.items[currentIndex]);
            $("#" + wish.items[currentIndex].id)
              .parents()
              .find($(".wish-btn > input"))
              .prop("checked", false);
            removeFromWish(wish.items[currentIndex].id);
          }, 400);
        });
      })();
    }
  };

  //Get Wish
  var getWish = function() {
    var myWish = wish;
    return myWish;
  };
});
```

```css
.wish__item {
  display: flex;
}

.my-wish-add {
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #6394f8;
}

.wish-btn {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wish-btn input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wish-icon.active {
  color: green;
}

.active i.fa.fa-wishlist__list {
  color: #6394f8;
}

.my-wish-remove {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
}

.my-wish-remove:hover {
  color: #464646;
}

.items__wish {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
}

.wish__info {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.wish__thumb {
  display: flex;
}

.wish__thumb img {
  height: 30px;
}

.wish-main {
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}

.wishlist__list {
  margin: 20px 0;
  float: right;
  background: #fff;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  right: 7.5%;
}

.wishlist__items li {
  list-style: none;
}

.wishlist__list-empty img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="wishlist">
  <div class="wishlist__list">
    <ul class="wishlist__items">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='products'>
  <div class="items__cart">
    <div id='headphones' class='item__title item__tile' data-wish="headphones">Product 1</div>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://www.iconasys.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/360-Product-Photography-White-Background-Acrylic-Riser-08.jpg">
    <div>
      <span>$</span>
      <span class='cost'>500</span>
    </div>
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></input></label>
  </div>
  <div class="items__cart">
    <div id='backpack' class='item__title item__tile' data-wish="backpack">Product 2</div>
    <div>
      <h4 class="count">200</h4>
    </div>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoqpSgkG4AQDQOe33jI1NiW3GW2JSB-_v36aREsVyFQH55JFOJ">
    <div>
      <span>$</span>
      <span class='cost'>460</span>
    </div>
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></label>
  </div>
  <div class="items__cart">
    <div id='handbag' class='item__title item__tile' data-wish="handbag">Product 3</div>
    <h4 class="count">400</h4>
    <img class="item__img" src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-de7d9680c4460296e461af9720a77d64">
    <div>
      <span>$</span>
      <span class='cost'>212</span>
    </div>
    <label class="wish-btn">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wish-check" class='my-wish-add'><i class="wish-icon far fa-heart"></i></label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you shopping for the user?

Comment: It's for a prototype. I need to demonstrate as if the user had items in their cart